# My partitions won't defrag

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, defragment

I can't defrag my partitions, I tried with windows software, with Smart Defrag, Defraggler and others

They all do the defragmentation process, but when I analyze again, I have the same fragmentation percent, which is already more than 25% even in one partition is 42% fragmented.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I would boot from a Windows 7 install disc, choose repair my computer option, then choose command prompt, run a chkdsk,

chkdsk /f

.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial147.html

Comment: Hi.. booted into a Windows 7 disc, entered recovery console and I did chkdsk /f... It fixed a couple of errors. But it doesn't recognize defrag as a command... So I booted in Windows again, and tried with Defraggler one more time and still the same result :S.

Comment: Oh, forgot you cannot run defrag from Windows RE, how much free space is there on those partitions?